# Elasticsearch - field_value_factor, missing parameter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, go

So i finally have setup the elasticsearch database and imported data into it.

Sometimes when i try to request data from frontend, i get 500 error( not all the time, just sometimes ).

I tried to request data from POSTMAN( to see the ES error message ).

I got:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[text][0]: query[filtered(function score (blended(terms: [url_words:test, domain_words:test, title:test, body:test]), functions: [{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@56319fc9]}{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@60b46f02]}]))->cache(_type:page)],from[0],size[25]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Missing value for field [lang_en]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][1]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[text][1]: query[filtered(function score (blended(terms: [url_words:test, domain_words:test, title:test, body:test]), functions: [{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@3ca7d41e]}{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@63daf999]}]))->cache(_type:page)],from[0],size[25]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Missing value for field [lang_en]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][2]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[text][2]: query[filtered(function score (blended(terms: [url_words:test, domain_words:test, title:test, body:test]), functions: [{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@27521539]}{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@66dbac2b]}]))->cache(_type:page)],from[0],size[25]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Missing value for field [lang_en]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][3]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[text][3]: query[filtered(function score (blended(terms: [url_words:test, domain_words:test, title:test, body:test]), functions: [{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@73bb4f5e]}{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@112dcf1c]}]))->cache(_type:page)],from[0],size[25]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Missing value for field [lang_en]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][4]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[text][4]: query[filtered(function score (blended(terms: [url_words:test, domain_words:test, title:test, body:test]), functions: [{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@b650549]}{filter(*:*), function [org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction@7fbe90f4]}]))->cache(_type:page)],from[0],size[25]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Missing value for field [lang_en]]; }]",
  "status": 500
}
```

Here is the request body:

```
{
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "multi_match": {
              "query": "test",
              "minimum_should_match": "-25%",
              "type": "cross_fields",
                  "tie_breaker": 0.5,
                  "fields": ["title^3", "body", "url_words^2", "domain_words^8"]
            }

          },
          "functions": [{
                "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "rank",
              "factor": 1
            }
        },{
                        "field_value_factor": {
                "field": "lang_en"
            }
                }]
        }
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 25
    }
```

I understand that Missing value for field [lang_en] is the problem. I toyed around es with google results, but without success.

ES version: 1.5.2

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

I added "missing": 0, to second `field_value_factor`, but i got this error instead:

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][0]: SearchParseException[[text][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"function_score\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"multi_match\": {\n              \"query\": \"test\",\n              \"minimum_should_match\": \"-25%\",\n              \"type\": \"cross_fields\",\n                  \"tie_breaker\": 0.5,\n                  \"fields\": [\"title^3\", \"body\", \"url_words^2\", \"domain_words^8\"]\n            }\n\n          },\n          \"functions\": [{\n                \"field_value_factor\": {\n              \"field\": \"rank\",\n              \"factor\": 1\n            }\n        },{\n                        \"field_value_factor\": {\n                \"field\": \"lang_en\",\n                \"missing\": 0\n            }\n                }]\n        }\n      },\n      \"from\": 0,\n      \"size\": 25\n    }\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[text] field_value_factor query does not support [missing]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][1]: SearchParseException[[text][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"function_score\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"multi_match\": {\n              \"query\": \"test\",\n              \"minimum_should_match\": \"-25%\",\n              \"type\": \"cross_fields\",\n                  \"tie_breaker\": 0.5,\n                  \"fields\": [\"title^3\", \"body\", \"url_words^2\", \"domain_words^8\"]\n            }\n\n          },\n          \"functions\": [{\n                \"field_value_factor\": {\n              \"field\": \"rank\",\n              \"factor\": 1\n            }\n        },{\n                        \"field_value_factor\": {\n                \"field\": \"lang_en\",\n                \"missing\": 0\n            }\n                }]\n        }\n      },\n      \"from\": 0,\n      \"size\": 25\n    }\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[text] field_value_factor query does not support [missing]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][2]: SearchParseException[[text][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"function_score\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"multi_match\": {\n              \"query\": \"test\",\n              \"minimum_should_match\": \"-25%\",\n              \"type\": \"cross_fields\",\n                  \"tie_breaker\": 0.5,\n                  \"fields\": [\"title^3\", \"body\", \"url_words^2\", \"domain_words^8\"]\n            }\n\n          },\n          \"functions\": [{\n                \"field_value_factor\": {\n              \"field\": \"rank\",\n              \"factor\": 1\n            }\n        },{\n                        \"field_value_factor\": {\n                \"field\": \"lang_en\",\n                \"missing\": 0\n            }\n                }]\n        }\n      },\n      \"from\": 0,\n      \"size\": 25\n    }\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[text] field_value_factor query does not support [missing]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][3]: SearchParseException[[text][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"function_score\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"multi_match\": {\n              \"query\": \"test\",\n              \"minimum_should_match\": \"-25%\",\n              \"type\": \"cross_fields\",\n                  \"tie_breaker\": 0.5,\n                  \"fields\": [\"title^3\", \"body\", \"url_words^2\", \"domain_words^8\"]\n            }\n\n          },\n          \"functions\": [{\n                \"field_value_factor\": {\n              \"field\": \"rank\",\n              \"factor\": 1\n            }\n        },{\n                        \"field_value_factor\": {\n                \"field\": \"lang_en\",\n                \"missing\": 0\n            }\n                }]\n        }\n      },\n      \"from\": 0,\n      \"size\": 25\n    }\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[text] field_value_factor query does not support [missing]]; }{[9m4uVcf3TLmQ9Kr7z_fSpQ][text][4]: SearchParseException[[text][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n      \"query\": {\n        \"function_score\": {\n          \"query\": {\n            \"multi_match\": {\n              \"query\": \"test\",\n              \"minimum_should_match\": \"-25%\",\n              \"type\": \"cross_fields\",\n                  \"tie_breaker\": 0.5,\n                  \"fields\": [\"title^3\", \"body\", \"url_words^2\", \"domain_words^8\"]\n            }\n\n          },\n          \"functions\": [{\n                \"field_value_factor\": {\n              \"field\": \"rank\",\n              \"factor\": 1\n            }\n        },{\n                        \"field_value_factor\": {\n                \"field\": \"lang_en\",\n                \"missing\": 0\n            }\n                }]\n        }\n      },\n      \"from\": 0,\n      \"size\": 25\n    }\n]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[text] field_value_factor query does not support [missing]]; }]",
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the dumb AWS ES version 1.5.2.

My solution: Create EC2 instance and deploy Elasticsearch manualy.

Comment: You'll still need to add the `missing` parameter to your query, upgrading alone is not sufficient, hence my answer still stands.

Comment: Glad we figured it out.

Answer (score 5):

In at least one document, the field `lang_en` is null, empty or simply non-existent.

You need to modify your `field_value_factor` function in order to tell it what to do in such as case, by using the `missing` setting with whatever default value makes sense (0, 1, etc):

```
{
    "field_value_factor": {
         "field": "lang_en",
         "missing": 1                <---- add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for response. I got an error, please check the question, i updated it!

Comment: Oh, `missing` is not yet available in 1.5.2 it only appeared in 1.6. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Is upgrading to 1.6 an option?

Comment: Does AWS let you upgrade ? Only solution i can see is to create EC2 instance and install es there.

Comment: Yes, it's an easy way out.